# How to set the date in a word document manipulated using OpenXML?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, openxml, openxml-sdk

I'm manipulating a word document using OpenXML and i have afield in that document to set the date. But the thing is when i insert the date like 01/10/2012, it get printed in the document as monday, October 10, 2012. That's not what i want. I want it to be like 01/10/2012. How can i do this?

@Hans @skynorth here's the code i'm using

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml;

namespace Inbay_Debrief_Report_Sender
{
    class InsertDetailsProgram
    {
        public static bool InsertDetals(string[] ObservationsValues, string[] ActiontakenValues, string[] ReccomendationsValues)
        {
            // convert template to document
            TemplateToDocument("DebriefReportTemplate.dotx", "DebriefReportTemplate.docx");

            using (WordprocessingDocument wordDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open("DebriefReportTemplate.docx", true))
            {
                List<SdtRun> sdtBlocks = new List<SdtRun>();
                sdtBlocks.AddRange(wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.ChildElements.OfType<SdtRun>());

                foreach (Paragraph para in wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.OfType<Paragraph>())
                {
                    var moreBlocks = para.ChildElements.OfType<SdtRun>();
                    if (moreBlocks != null && moreBlocks.Count() > 0)
                        sdtBlocks.AddRange(moreBlocks);
                }

                foreach (SdtRun block in sdtBlocks)
                {
                    if (block.SdtProperties != null)
                    {
                        Tag tag = block.SdtProperties.ChildElements.OfType<Tag>().ElementAt(0);

                        switch (tag.Val.Value)
                        {

                            case "caseTag":
                                block.ModifyContent(Variables.CaseNumber);
                                break;

                            case "nameTag":
                                block.ModifyContent(Variables.CustomerName);
                                break;

                            case "typeTag":
                                block.ModifyContent(Variables.MachineType);
                                break;

                            case "dateTag":
                                block.ModifyContent(Variables.ReportedDate); // this is where i insert the date
                                break;

                            case "engineerTag":
                                block.ModifyContent(Variables.EngineerName);
                                break;



                            case "virusTag":
                                if (Variables.virus == true) { block.Check(); }
                                else { block.UnCheck(); }
                                break;

                            case "diagnosticTag":
                                if (Variables.Diagnostic == true) { block.Check(); }
                                else { block.UnCheck(); }
                                break;

                            case "osupgradeTag":
                                if (Variables.OSUpgrade == true)
                                { block.Check(); }
                                else
                                { block.UnCheck(); }
                                break;

                            case "backupTag":
                                if (Variables.DataBackup == true)
                                { block.Check(); }
                                else
                                { block.UnCheck(); }
                                break;

                            case "datarecoveryTag":
                                if (Variables.DataRecovery == true)
                                { block.Check(); }
                                else
                                { block.UnCheck(); }
                                break;

                            case "softwareTag":
                                if (Variables.SoftwareInstallation == true)
                                { block.Check(); }
                                else
                                { block.UnCheck(); }
                                break;

                            case "datacleanseTag":
                                if (Variables.DataCleanse == true)
                                { block.Check(); }
                                else
                                { block.UnCheck(); }
                                break;

                            case "gadgetTag":
                                if (Variables.GadgetInstallation == true)
                                { block.Check(); }
                                else
                                { block.UnCheck(); }
                                break;

                            case "computersetTag":
                                if (Variables.DataBackup == true)
                                { block.Check(); }
                                else
                                { block.UnCheck(); }
                                break;

                            case "parentalTag":
                                if (Variables.ParentalControl == true)
                                { block.Check(); }
                                else
                                { block.UnCheck(); }
                                break;

                            case "smartphoneTag":
                                if (Variables.SmartPhone == true)
                                { block.Check(); }
                                else
                                { block.UnCheck(); }
                                break;

                            case "factoryresetTag":
                                if (Variables.FactoryReset == true)
                                { block.Check(); }
                                else
                                { block.UnCheck(); }
                                break;

                            case "emailsetupTag":
                                if (Variables.Email == true)
                                { block.Check(); }
                                else
                                { block.UnCheck(); }
                                break;

                            case "networkingTag":
                                if (Variables.Networking == true)
                                { block.Check(); }
                                else
                                { block.UnCheck(); }
                                break;

                            case "tuneupTag":
                                if (Variables.Tuneup == true)
                                { block.Check(); }
                                else
                                { block.UnCheck(); }
                                break;

                            case "broadbandTag":
                                if (Variables.Broadband == true)
                                { block.Check(); }
                                else
                                { block.UnCheck(); }
                                break;




                            case "observationsArea":
                                List<string> dynamicList = new List<string>(ObservationsValues);
                                List<Paragraph> newChildren = CreateNewChildren(dynamicList);
                                Paragraph oldChild = block.Parent as Paragraph;

                                oldChild.ParagraphProperties.SpacingBetweenLines.After = "0";
                                oldChild.ParagraphProperties.SpacingBetweenLines.Before = "0";

                                newChildren.ForEach(ch =>
                                {
                                    oldChild = wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.InsertAfter(ch, oldChild);
                                });
                                break;


                            case "actionsTakenArea":
                                List<string> dynamicList1 = new List<string>(ActiontakenValues);
                                List<Paragraph> newChildren1 = CreateNewChildren(dynamicList1);
                                Paragraph oldChild1 = block.Parent as Paragraph;

                                var oldChildSibling = oldChild1.PreviousSibling() as Paragraph;
                                if (oldChildSibling.InnerText.Length == 0)
                                    oldChildSibling.Remove();

                                oldChild1.ParagraphProperties.SpacingBetweenLines.After = "0";
                                oldChild1.ParagraphProperties.SpacingBetweenLines.Before = "0";

                                // now if you want some space, change the values of After & Before

                                newChildren1.ForEach(ch =>
                                {
                                    oldChild1 = wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.InsertAfter(ch, oldChild1);
                                });
                                break;

                            case "reccomendationsArea":
                                List<string> dynamicList2 = new List<string>(ReccomendationsValues);
                                List<Paragraph> newChildren2 = CreateNewChildren(dynamicList2);
                                Paragraph oldChild2 = block.Parent as Paragraph;

                                var oldChildSibling1 = oldChild2.PreviousSibling() as Paragraph;
                                if (oldChildSibling1.InnerText.Length == 0)
                                    oldChildSibling1.Remove();

                                oldChild2.ParagraphProperties.SpacingBetweenLines.After = "0";
                                oldChild2.ParagraphProperties.SpacingBetweenLines.Before = "0";

                                // now if you want some space, change the values of After & Before

                                newChildren2.ForEach(ch =>
                                {
                                    oldChild2 = wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.InsertAfter(ch, oldChild2);
                                });
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                }

                // save the document
                wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Save();


            }

            return true;
        }


        private static List<Paragraph> CreateNewChildren(List<string> dynamicList)
        {
            List<Paragraph> newParaCollection = new List<Paragraph>();

            dynamicList.ForEach(item =>
            {
                Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph() { RsidParagraphMarkRevision = "008C2139", RsidParagraphAddition = "008C2139", RsidParagraphProperties = "00050C00", RsidRunAdditionDefault = "008C2139" };

                ParagraphProperties paragraphProperties1 = new ParagraphProperties() { SpacingBetweenLines = new SpacingBetweenLines() { After = "0", Before = "0" } };
                ParagraphStyleId paragraphStyleId1 = new ParagraphStyleId() { Val = "ListParagraph" };

                NumberingProperties numberingProperties1 = new NumberingProperties();
                NumberingLevelReference numberingLevelReference1 = new NumberingLevelReference() { Val = 0 };
                NumberingId numberingId1 = new NumberingId() { Val = 1 };

                numberingProperties1.Append(numberingLevelReference1);
                numberingProperties1.Append(numberingId1);

                ParagraphBorders paragraphBorders1 = new ParagraphBorders();
                TopBorder topBorder1 = new TopBorder() { Val = BorderValues.Single, Color = "auto", Size = (UInt32Value)6U, Space = (UInt32Value)1U };
                BottomBorder bottomBorder1 = new BottomBorder() { Val = BorderValues.Single, Color = "auto", Size = (UInt32Value)6U, Space = (UInt32Value)1U };

                // paragraphBorders1.Append(topBorder1);
                // paragraphBorders1.Append(bottomBorder1);

                ParagraphMarkRunProperties paragraphMarkRunProperties1 = new ParagraphMarkRunProperties();
                RunStyle runStyle1 = new RunStyle() { Val = "Style1" };
                FontSize fontSize1 = new FontSize() { Val = "29.5" };

                paragraphMarkRunProperties1.Append(runStyle1);
                paragraphMarkRunProperties1.Append(fontSize1);

                paragraphProperties1.Append(paragraphStyleId1);
                paragraphProperties1.Append(numberingProperties1);

                //if (dynamicList.IndexOf(item) == dynamicList.Count - 1)
                //{
                //    paragraphProperties1.Append(paragraphBorders1);
                //}

                paragraphProperties1.Append(paragraphMarkRunProperties1);

                Run run1 = new Run();

                RunProperties runProperties1 = new RunProperties();
                RunStyle runStyle2 = new RunStyle() { Val = "Style1" };
                FontSize fontSize2 = new FontSize() { Val = "29.5" };
                FontSizeComplexScript fontSizeComplexScript1 = new FontSizeComplexScript() { Val = "18" };

                Bold BoldObj = new Bold() { Val = false };
                runProperties1.Append(runStyle2);
                runProperties1.Append(fontSize2);
                runProperties1.Append(BoldObj);
                runProperties1.Append(fontSizeComplexScript1);
                Text text1 = new Text();
                text1.Text = item;

                run1.Append(runProperties1);
                run1.Append(text1);

                paragraph.Append(paragraphProperties1);
                paragraph.Append(run1);
                newParaCollection.Add(paragraph);

            });

            return newParaCollection;
        }

        private static void TemplateToDocument(string templateFile, string documentFile)
        {
            MemoryStream presentationStream = null;

            using (Stream tplStream = File.Open(templateFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                presentationStream = new MemoryStream((int)tplStream.Length);
                tplStream.Copy(presentationStream);
                presentationStream.Position = 0L;
            }

            using (WordprocessingDocument wordPackage = WordprocessingDocument.Open(presentationStream, true))
            {
                wordPackage.ChangeDocumentType(DocumentFormat.OpenXml.WordprocessingDocumentType.Document);
                MainDocumentPart docPart = wordPackage.MainDocumentPart;
                docPart.AddExternalRelationship("http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/attachedTemplate",
                   new Uri(templateFile, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));

                docPart.Document.Save();
            }

            File.WriteAllBytes(documentFile, presentationStream.ToArray());
        }
    }

    public static class Extensions
    {
        public static void Copy(this Stream source, Stream target)
        {
            if (source != null)
            {
                MemoryStream mstream = source as MemoryStream;
                if (mstream != null) mstream.WriteTo(target);
                else
                {
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
                    int length = buffer.Length, size;
                    while ((size = source.Read(buffer, 0, length)) != 0)
                        target.Write(buffer, 0, size);
                }
            }
        }

        public static void ModifyContent(this SdtRun block, string content)
        {
            SdtContentRun contentBlock = block.ChildElements.OfType<SdtContentRun>().ElementAt(0);
            Run run = contentBlock.ChildElements.OfType<Run>().ElementAt(0);
            if (run != null)
            {
                Text text = run.GetFirstChild<Text>();
                text.Text = content;
            }
        }

        public static void Check(this SdtRun block)
        {

            DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Office2010.Word.SdtContentCheckBox chkBox = block.SdtProperties.GetFirstChild<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Office2010.Word.SdtContentCheckBox>();
            chkBox.Checked.Val = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Office2010.Word.OnOffValues.One;


            block.ModifyContent("☒");
        }

        public static void UnCheck(this SdtRun block)
        {

            DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Office2010.Word.SdtContentCheckBox chkBox = block.SdtProperties.GetFirstChild<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Office2010.Word.SdtContentCheckBox>();
            chkBox.Checked.Val = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Office2010.Word.OnOffValues.Zero;


            block.ModifyContent("☐");


        }
    }




}
```

Comment: What do you mean by field? A field you inserted via the word insert menu->Quick Parts->Field?

Comment: We need code relevant to the problem.

Comment: Could you please provide some code? Especially the code setting the Text property of the FieldCode instance.

Comment: @Hans i have edited my post with a code

Comment: @skynorth take a look at the code

Comment: @aroshlakshan No one is going to look at code that big. 95% of that code isn't necessary. And you still didn't give us the most important part. To what `Variables.ReportedDate` gets set or what sets it.

Comment: What kind of content control do you use? A rich text box, a text box or a date content control?

Answer (score 1):

You have to find the Text element inside the sdtContent and replace it with a new one that has been formatted according to your needs.

So you need something like that (untested, may need to edit the first line):

```
var dateRun = block.GetFirstChild<SdtContentRun>().GetFirstChild<Run>();
dateRun.RemoveAllChildren<Text>();
dateRun.AppendChild(new Text(now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy", new CultureInfo("en-US"))));
```